# Can new kernel be deleted?

Tags: 10.10, kernel

i upgrade from lucid to maverick and got pretty messy  i reinstall ubuntu maverick from live cd and so far i just had to reinstall all applications i had.

but i have this list of kernel

linux-image-2.6.35-22-generic        2.6.35-22.35
linux-image-2.6.35-28-generic        2.6.35-28.50
linux-image-generic                  2.6.35.28.36

and im using currently this version

Linux 2.6.35-22-generic i686

im not sure if it's safe to delete the new kernel.

Comment: Duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/17432/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-old-kernels-from-menu-lst

Answer (score 2):

Some times new kernel can result in some driver incompatibilities, so it is safe to roll back to older version until the matter is resolved.
You can simply chose old version of kernel(or make it default). If you are using grub 2
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275 (refer point 7).

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to **uninstall** the new kernel.
Go to System > Administration > Synaptic Package Manager and look for *linux-image* and *linux-headers*.

But why you want to do that?
If the answer is "because I'm using currently this version Linux 2.6.35-22-generic i686", you should just [configure Grub](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202) to start this kernel instead of other.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ubuntu-tweak to clean up kernel. If you have perfectly working other kernels. Then you are free to go