# Error when updating Ubuntu Server to new version

Tags: 11.10, server, initramfs

Today I updated Ubuntu Server 11.04 to 11.10 and after a rather fast update I got the following error:

```
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-server

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-server with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu7) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-server

gzip: stdout: No space left on device
cpio: write error: Broken pipe
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 1 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.0.0-12-server with 1.
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

Need to add that I can connect normally to the server via SSH. It reboots well with no problems and I can install and do anything BUT this error appears when I install/remove anything. It was the only error when updating I even updated via SSH with no other problems.

Comment: oops- looks like you've run out of space on your root or /boot partition - can you add the output of `df`

Comment: OMG Foss You are right -.-. Did not read that little part about space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have enough space on your disk:

> gzip: stdout: No space left on device

One way to do this would be to remove old kernels:

- [Is it safe to delete the old kernels from menu.lst?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17432/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-old-kernels-from-menu-lst)

Comment: Hey ROBOT, if you can add a way to remove the older kernels with no problem it would help more just to be in the safe side.

Comment: @Luis - LOL - I like your answer in that link - slightly ironic?!