# MySQL does not start up on ubuntu 12

Tags: 12.04, mysql

MySQL Server does not start up on ubuntu 12.  When I run the status command, the following message is displayed:

ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Any suggestions to fix this issue (and hopefully avoid this going forward) will be welcome.

Edit: The process is not running - I forgot to mention that in the post.  Should I go about changing the mysql.cnf file to point to a different location for the socket location (or perhaps add a link to it)?

Comment: please share useful suggestions - hope no one takes offense to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/79226/cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run-mysqld-mysqld-sock)

Comment: the error message may be the same but what's causing it might not be - I don't have a firewall blocking the port, disk is not out of space, my.cnf points to 127.0.0.1.  Any suggestions to troubleshoot  and/or fix the issue would be quite welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up re-installing ubuntu and mysql in order to fix the issue.  I will update the post if I come across the same issue and can come up with a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command in Terminal:

```
sudo service mysql status
```

If the output is something like:

```
mysql stop/waiting
```

Then mysql server is not running on your machine. Try:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

And try to connect again.

Comment: I think I was not clear in the post - when I mentioned MySQL does not start, it meant that the process is not up.  Startup is not working through service mysql start option.  Thanks

Comment: I ended up re-installing ubuntu and mysql