# which kernels can I safely purge?

Tags: kernel, cleanup

I use the main answer of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17432/is-it-safe-to-delete-the-old-kernels-from-menu-lst) quite often to clear some space, but now I'm in extreme need and I'd like to better understand which kernels are safe to purge, my list is the following

```
10:50:58-673 - ~> dpkg -l | grep -Eo "^.i +linux-(image|headers)[^ ]+" | cut -c 5- | grep --color -E "$|"`uname -r`
linux-headers-2.6.38-15
linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic
linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
linux-headers-2.6.38-16
linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic
linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic-pae # current one
linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-generic-pae
linux-headers-server
linux-image-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
linux-image-2.6.38-16-generic-pae
linux-image-generic-pae
linux-image-server
```

Is it enough to keep

```
linux-headers-2.6.38-15
linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic
linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
linux-headers-2.6.38-16
linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic
linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic-pae # current one
```

Or would this be enough

```
linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic-pae
linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic-pae # current one
```

Or which other would be the shortest (keeping the previous one too)? And why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're using the generic-pae kernels; it's safe to remove the `-server` kernels, which you aren't using.

You *must* keep at least one kernel image (`linux-image-2.6.38-16-generic-pae`, etc.). It's recommended to keep at least 2, because if an update hoses the most recent kernel, you can still boot using the previous one.

You should also keep `linux-image-generic-pae`, which is a tiny meta-package that causes the latest kernel to be installed.

You should keep the corresponding headers for each kernel you keep; the headers are needed to build kernel modules for that kernel.

Comment: so you're saying `linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic-pae linux-headers-2.6.38-16-generic-pae linux-image-2.6.38-15-generic-pae linux-image-2.6.38-16-generic-pae`

Comment: as I'm using `linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic-pae` this is needed too `linux-headers-2.6.38-15-generic` !!!