# Chroot with specific kernel

Tags: kernel, chroot

I need to build some old drivers with specific kernel version.

The Kernel `2.6.31-20-generic` is needed. I have tried to built it on Ubuntu 12.04 and the new one, 14.04 with no success. The only one working is `2.6.31-20`, such answer I get when I asked how to build it.

How to make chroot with such version of kernel?

Comment: I have finally installed Ubuntu 9.10 on VirutalBox and updated kernel to 2.6.31-20-generic.

Answer (score 4):

`chroot` just uses your current Kernel. That's just how it works. If you need to change the enveloping kernel, you're going to need to virtualise (through something like `kvm` or VirtualBox)... Or roll your kernel back to the version your chroot is using (though this sounds painful for the versions we're talking about).

I would personally just look at building for the right script. If you're using DKMS for this, it's fairly simple to just tell it which kernel and arch to build for:

```
sudo dkms install nvidia-337 -k 2.6.31-20-generic
```

The `dkms {remove,build,install,uninstall,status,...}` subcommands all take a `-k` option for specifying the kernel and arch. See `man dkms` for a bit more information.

For a list of the installed kernels, `ls /lib/modules` should get you moving in the right direction though it may feature kernels that are no longer installed. If you want a more packaged list, you can use [a previous answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/17485/449):

```
dpkg -l | awk '/^.i +linux-(im|he)/ && $2~/[0-9]/ {print $2}'
```