# Is keeping generic linux-image and linux-headers necessary?

Tags: apt, 20.04, kernel, purge

I want to do a cleanup. After somethings I did:

```
$ uname -a
Linux <OS_name> 5.8.0-49-generic #55~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 26 01:01:07 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And then:

```
$ dpkg --list | egrep -i --color 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }'
linux-headers-5.8.0-49-generic
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-image-5.8.0-49-generic
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04
linux-modules-5.8.0-49-generic
linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-49-generic
```

Now I want to know "Is keeping `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` necessary? I want to do `apt purge` for cleaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I remove old kernel versions to clean up the boot menu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) and [Is it safe to delete the old kernels from menu.lst?](https://askubuntu.com/q/17432/)

Comment: Yes it is necessary to keep these two packages. `linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04` and `linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04` packages ensure you always have the most up to date kernel version installed (these two packages will always depend on the newest kernel version for update purposes). It appears that you have already deleted the older kernels as only version 5.8.0-49 exists. There is nothing more to do. This looks good.